# Render View with content-type as "application/json" renders a Raw HTML on the screen

Tags: asp.net, json, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a web application which worked perfectly fine earlier, and the content-type in the Headers for the html page being rendered was "text/html". There is a change in the requirement where the page needs to be rendered with content-type as "application/json".

I did not set this value explicitly anywhere before. However, when I add the line 
    HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
to my controller right before returning the View, the View no longer is displayed as before, however, I see the Raw HTML content on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you insert HTML markup into a web page? And why do you still send plain HTML if a browser expects a json string (according to the new value of the HTTP Content-Type header)?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt here, but I am not sure how to read Json inside a View. The code works fine with html content. I don't know how to parse a Json content type. Is there an example which I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON strings are mostly used for data exchange between client and server or service. It has a specific format and is processed in a specific way by jquery. If you sent an "application/json"-type response, jquery may encode/decode the response result. Therefore it is inserted as is.

A solution depends on the certain requirement. Nevertheless, if you need to get HTML markup, but you have to send data in the json format, send the markup as a property of your JSON object. On the client side, get the property value and insert it into the page markup.